# Update UILabel in UICollectionViewCell outside collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell in a UICollectionView in a ViewController defined in IB. In the cell there is a label that I am able to set and modify text property in cellForItemAtIndexPath. What I want to achieve is change the text property in UILabel for a selected cell. When the cell is selected in didSelectItemAtIndexPath I store the  indexPath. I want to do the update at a button click (a button outside the collection view) and set text property of UILabel to button title (pressedNumber).

I have tried this:

```
-(BOOL) calculate: (NSString *) pressedNumber{

talCell *cell = [self.collectionView
                 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                 forIndexPath:selectedCell];


[cell.cellTitle setText:pressedNumber];
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedCell]];
```

When debugging I can see that cell.cellTitle.text property is same as pressedNumber.
Appreciate any advice that could lead me to the correct code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the indexPath of the cell, get it with with cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
talCell *cell = [self.collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];


[cell.cellTitle setText:pressedNumber];
```

Comment: I tried this     talCell *cell = [self.collectionView
                     cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedCell]; But get 
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'talCell *__strong' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'

Comment: you probably need to cast if you use a custom cell: talCell *cell = (talCell *)[self.collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];